# Recursive Depth-first search algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search

I am trying to write a recursive depth-first search algorithm that takes an adjacency list representing a graph and prints the visit order of the vertices.

My input is a graph stored as an adjacency list:

```
graphAL2 = {0 : [1,2,3],
        1 : [0,3,4],
        2 : [0,4,5],
        3 : [0,1,5],
        4 : [1,2],
        5 : [2,3] }
```

From there, I have written 2 functions, a main and a secondary function, that make up the program.

```
import sys

def main():
count = 0
graphAL2v = {}

for key, value in graphAL2.items():
    graphAL2v[key] = 0

print graphAL2v

for key in graphAL2v: 
    if key == 0: 
        dfs(key, count, graphAL2v)
def dfs(v, count, graph):
    count = count + 1 
    graph[v] = count
    for key in graph: 
        if key == 0:
            dfs(key, count, graph)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Right now my if I run it, the output is:

```
{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}
{0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}
```

and the first value paired with key 0 keeps incrementing until a

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

is reached. The for loop should be going through the rest of the key-pair values and changing the values to the order that the vertex was visited but I'm not sure why it isn't doing so.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Since the first key in `graph` is 0, you always send off your recursive call `dfs(key, count, graph)` in the first iteration of the `for` loop. Although I'm not sure why you're checking `key == 0`, or how your algorithm is supposed to work.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Basically i'm taking the input vertices and marking them all with 0's to show that they haven't been visited yet. If a vertex hasn't been visited, it gets passed into the second function that then alters the 0 to the number corresponding to when the vertex was visited. Since vertex 0 is visited first, its value gets changed from 0 to 1, and then the function should move on to the next vertex, change its value from 0 to 2, and so on and so forth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in your `dfs()` function , you are not checking whether the node has already been visited or not , you are checking whether the node is `0` or not in the `if` condition - `if key == 0:` , so it keeps recursing for `0`th node, even though it has already been visited.

And due to this indefinite recursion for `0`th node, when the maximum recursion limit is reached, it pops out with the error - `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` .

You should check the value for `key` from graph` , not the graph itself. And you are not using the adjacency list anywhere either. You should loop based on the adjacency list, not the visited dictionary.

Example -

```
graphAL2 = {0 : [1,2,3],
        1 : [0,3,4],
        2 : [0,4,5],
        3 : [0,1,5],
        4 : [1,2],
        5 : [2,3] }

def main():
    count = 0
    graphAL2v = {}

    for key, value in graphAL2.items():
         graphAL2v[key] = 0

    print(graphAL2v)

    for key in graphAL2v: 
        if graphAL2v[key] == 0: 
            dfs(key, count, graphAL2, graphAL2v)

    print(graphAL2v)


def dfs(v, count, graphal, graphvisited):
    count = count + 1
    print("Visiting ",v)
    graphvisited[v] = count
    for elem in graphal[v]:
        if not graphvisited[elem]:
            dfs(elem, count, graphal, graphvisited)

main()
```

Demo -

```
{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}
Visiting  0
Visiting  1
Visiting  3
Visiting  5
Visiting  2
Visiting  4
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 5, 3: 3, 4: 6, 5: 4}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! I understand where the error was now and can't believe I didn't think that would be what was causing it. Quick question, now that my code reflects the changes to fix the problem, I'm now getting a `"TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` error on the `for elem in graphal[v]:` line, any suggestions there?

Comment: what are you sending in `graphal`? Can you update the updated code in question?

Comment: The firs time I called `dfs()` in main, I had swapped the last 2 parameters. I switched those and now the error is gone and results are produced. Thank you again! (Another side note, for breadth-first search it would essentially be the same skeleton, but the second function would need to be changed to accommodate how breadth-first search works right?)